# Producing a minimiser for the Kantorovich problem from a minimiser of the Beckmann flow problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, optimal-transportation

**Notation:** We denote by $\mathcal M$ the set of vector valued measures on $\mathbb R^d$ whose divergence is a scalar measure (in the weak sense).

**Definitions:** Consider the Beckmann flow minimisation problem (BP):

$\min \{ \int |\mathbf w (x)| dx: \mathbf w \in \mathcal M, \nabla . \mathbf w = \mu - \nu\}$

for given probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb R^d$.

We denote also by (KP) the associated Kantorovich problem for the cost $c(x, y) = |x - y|$ with the same measures $\mu$ and $\nu$.

It is known that (BP) and (KP) both admit minimizers. Also, given a minimizer of (KP), there is a way to explicitly produce a minimizer of (BP).

> **Question:** Can we go the other way? In other words, given a solution $\mathbf w$ of (BP), is there a way to explicitly produce a
> solution $\gamma$ of (KP)? By "explicitly produce" I mean, vaguely, a
> way to write $\gamma$ in terms of $\mathbf w$.

Comment: I think that the answer is yes and can be found in Filippo Santambrogio's "OT for applied mathematics" book, but I don't know any details from the top of my head...